# Benchmark Redis under Twemproxy with redis-benchmark

Tags: redis, benchmarking, twemproxy

I am trying to test a very simple setup with Redis and Twemproxy but I can't find a way to make it faster.

I have 2 redis servers that I run with bare minimum configuration:

```
./redis-server --port 6370
./redis-server --port 6371
```

Both of the compiled from source and running under 1 machine with all the appropriate memory and CPUs.

If I run a redis-benchmark in one of the instances I get the following:

```
./redis-benchmark --csv -q -p 6371 -t set,get,incr,lpush,lpop,sadd,spop -r 100000000

"SET","161290.33"
"GET","176366.86"
"INCR","170940.17"
"LPUSH","178571.42"
"LPOP","168350.17"
"SADD","176991.16"
"SPOP","168918.92"
```

Now I would like to use Twemproxy in front of the two instances to distribute the requests and get a higher throughput (at least this is what I expected!).

I used the following configuration for Twemproxy:

```
my_cluster:
     listen: 127.0.0.1:6379
     hash: fnv1a_64
     distribution: ketama
     auto_eject_hosts: false
     redis: true
     servers:
      - 127.0.0.1:6371:1 server1
      - 127.0.0.1:6372:1 server2
```

And I run nutcracker as:

```
./nutcracker -c twemproxy_redis.yml -i 5
```

The results are very disappointing:

```
./redis-benchmark -r 1000000 --csv -q -p 6379 -t set,get,incr,lpush,lpop,sadd,spop-q -p 6379

"SET","112485.94"
"GET","113895.21"
"INCR","110987.79"
"LPUSH","145560.41"
"LPOP","149700.61"
"SADD","122100.12"
```

I tried to understand what is going on by getting Twemproxy's statistics as this:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 22222
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
{
  "service": "nutcracker",
  "source": "localhost.localdomain",
  "version": "0.4.1",
  "uptime": 10,
  "timestamp": 1452545028,
  "total_connections": 303,
  "curr_connections": 3,
  "my_cluster": {
    "client_eof": 300,
    "client_err": 0,
    "client_connections": 0,
    "server_ejects": 0,
    "forward_error": 0,
    "fragments": 0,
    "server1": {
      "server_eof": 0,
      "server_err": 0,
      "server_timedout": 0,
      "server_connections": 1,
      "server_ejected_at": 0,
      "requests": 246791,
      "request_bytes": 11169484,
      "responses": 246791,
      "response_bytes": 1104215,
      "in_queue": 0,
      "in_queue_bytes": 0,
      "out_queue": 0,
      "out_queue_bytes": 0
    },
    "server2": {
      "server_eof": 0,
      "server_err": 0,
      "server_timedout": 0,
      "server_connections": 1,
      "server_ejected_at": 0,
      "requests": 353209,
      "request_bytes": 12430516,
      "responses": 353209,
      "response_bytes": 2422648,
      "in_queue": 0,
      "in_queue_bytes": 0,
      "out_queue": 0,
      "out_queue_bytes": 0
    }
  }
}
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Is there any other benchmark around that works properly? Or `redis-benchmark` should had worked?

I forgot to mention that I am using Redis: 3.0.6 and Twemproxy: 0.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might seem counter-intuitive, but putting two instances of redis with a proxy in front of them will certainly reduce performance!

In a single instance scenario, redis-benchmark connects directly to the redis server, and thus has minimal latency per request.

Once you put two instances and a single twemproxy in front of them, think what happens - you connect to twemproxy, which analyzes the request, chooses the right instance, and connects to it.

So, first of all, each request now has two network hops to travel instead of one. Added latency means less throughput of course.

Also, you are using just one twemproxy instance. So let's assume that twemproxy itself performs more or less like a single redis instance, you can never beat a single instance with a single proxy.

Twemproxy facilitates scaling out, not scaling up. It allows you to grow your cluster to sizes that a single instance could never achieve. But there's a latency price to pay, and as long as you're using a single proxy, it's also a throughput price.

Comment: Great answer -> +1. I disagree, however, firstly with the absolute tone of "certainly reduce performance!" :) There cases in which a proxy actually **improves** performance (e.g. by keeping low connection counts, doing implicit pipelining and keeping persistent connections) so that makes it very case dependent. Also, you can save most of the extra hop's latency if the proxy and the instances are on the same server (doable in some cases at least). Lastly a single proxy may use multiple threads so it _may_ beat a single Redis by parallelizing across requests multiple Redises #JustSayin'

Comment: @ItamarHaber the entire experiment was done on a single machine, so I guess the CPU utilization also comes into play, assuming 2-4 cores. But yes, in theory if you have say 4 cores, 2 redis instances and one twemproxy with 2 io threads, and you run redis-benchmark externally, you just might see a throughput increase in longer operations. In short ones (get/set) I'd say the bottleneck is latency so you won't see much change.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Do you have any recommendations on what would be a scenario for me to setup so I could see a performance gain? e.g. If I ask from redis-benchmark to have more connections? Or something else??

Comment: Also if I understand correctly, the problem of reduced performance is due to extra latency and not due to throughput saturation right?

Comment: @ΑναστάσηςΑνδρονίδης try pipelining maybe, add `-P 500` to the redis-benchmark args

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer with `-P` is even worst XD. The twemproxy runs x4 slower... `"SET","144092.22"` for twemproxy, `"SET","377358.50"` for the single.

Comment: @ΑναστάσηςΑνδρονίδης hmmm, it could be the way that twemproxy handles pipelines.

Comment: This is not related to scaling up versus out which I believe just clouds the issue. The question is why isn't the throughput increasing when he scales out the system.

Comment: @RickO'Shea you will see a scaling improvement with more instances I suppose. And obviously with more load-balanced twemproxies.

Comment: @RickO'Shea also this is really comparing apples and oranges. the real comparison should be one instance behind twemproxy vs two instances behind one twemproxy, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The proxy imposes a small tax on each request. Measure throughput using the proxy with one server. Impose a load until the throughput stops growing and the response times slow to a crawl. Add another server and note the response times are restored to normal, while capacity just doubled. Of course, you'll want to add servers well before response times start to crawl.